# What is the POSIX c99 utility usually implemented as on Linux systems?

Tags: posix, c99

I am curious what the [POSIX c99 utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) is usually implemented as in GNU/Linux distributions.

I realize that this is really a question that should be answered by each distribution's documentation, but both the manpage on my openSUSE 11.4 install and [Ubuntu's manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/c99.1posix.html) basically just list similar information as the POSIX standard, without specifying what the compiler actually is (i.e., is it GCC, Clang or something else).

So does anyone know what the common practice is? My guess would be that it is a wraper for gcc with the -std=c99 option, perhaps with -pedantic added to conform more closely with the C99 standard.

Comment: If you think of c99 as doing exactly what POSIX c99 is supposed to do, why would you care whether it's gcc or clang under the hood?

Comment: @Jens: you don't pick a compiler by standards conformance *alone*. If it produces slow code, you'd go looking for something else that can compile C99 code.

Comment: @lasmans: While this may be true, I think it does not apply to the question (and the speed of code by compiler has not a black and white answer either as it may depend on many options). This is why I inquire for Quantumboredom's underlying motivation. There must be more to it than just c99 compiler vendor statistics by distro, which by itself is a rather useless information.

Comment: It was really just curiosity, and it's interesting to know whether it's an acceptable compiler to use in most cases (from a performance and compatibility standpoint). Since it turns out that (at least on my system) it is probably gcc -std=c99 -pedantic, it should be fine to use as long as no extra gcc options are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it's indeed a wrapper for `gcc -std=c99`, though it might select a compiler based on the environment variable `CC`. You can check for yourself by doing `file /usr/bin/c99` and reading it if it's a shell script, or checking where it points to if it's a symlink.

Comment: On my system (openSUSE 11.4) it's actually an executable: "/usr/bin/c99: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, stripped". I too was expecting it to be either a symlink or a script. Opening the executable with vim does show this (among the gibberish): "B^@malloc^@-std=c99^@-pedantic^@cD:EgI:l:L:o:OsU:^@missing operand^@/usr/bin/gcc^@execv(/usr/bin/gcc)^@^". So it is probably gcc -std=c99 -pedantic, at least on my system.

Comment: @Quantumboredom: the stuff between the gibberish can be extracted using the `strings` command.